# Delete session from database after it expired?

Tags: c#, sql-server, session

This might be a silly question but i was wondering if it would be a good idea to delete all expired "sessions" from my database, every 15 minutes?

Or just leave it there? Session expires after X minutes, its no longer useful anymore, seems like it just taking up space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When my team deploys SQL Server session state in a .NET application, we simply create a job with SQL Server Agent to clean up the expired sessions nightly (or at some appropriate interval).

Unless you have massive amounts of traffic, you can do this whenever it is convenient without worrying about instantly deleting unused sessions, but it's definitely a good idea to clean up.

Comment: Thanks! Yeh might be best to clean up on off peak. Btw does the database shrink itself when the records are deleted?

Comment: If DB performance is important to you, you should avoid running DBCC SHRINKFILE on a production database. Shrinking the database files means that when they grow again, the files aren't contiguous, which increases disk seeks. Also, the process of growing files is fairly expensive.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the standard SQL Server Session State, old sessions are automatically deleted for you. Until the old entries are deleted, sessions do not expire, since the provider does not actively monitor the Expires column in the session table.

The install / configuration utility creates a SQL Agent job that calls the `DeleteExpiredSessions` stored procedure every 60 seconds. This means that SQL Agent needs to be running for session expiration to work and for the table to get cleaned up.

Comment: Hi @RickNZ. This is horrible behaviour, which we have just noticed in our system and it hurts! Are you aware of any fixes or alternative SQL providers that function in a more expected manner rather than relying on session entries being physically deleted from the database?

Comment: I'm not aware of any open source alternative SQL providers. This isn't the only problem with the standard provider, so what I often suggest for large projects is writing your own replacement provider. I've done this myself; the level of effort involved isn't as large as you might think, and the performance gains can be significant.

Answer (score 0):

If your table looks like that

```
SessionId datatype,
SessionLastTouch datetime
```

then when registering the new session do some cleanup after writing(session issue or touch) to the table, like this:

```
delete from YourSessionsRegister WHERE SessionLastTouch < DATEADD(min, -15, GETDATE())
```

**BUT**

May be better way is to cleanup the session register based on some schedule - to reduce DB load in peak hours - simply create the job, which cleans up the register every night or smth. like this