# Custom SQL Server Session Provider in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session, customization, session-state

Implementing the SQL Server Session Provider by using aspnet_regsql.

In Web Config

```
<sessionState mode ="SQLServer" cookieless="false" timeout="1" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" sqlConnectionString="Password=ads;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=ASPState;Data Source=DF" />
```

When Session is created the new row is added for that session in database, but when session expires it is not deleting the row. whether we manually need to customize the method for deleting the expired session? If yes, explian the methods we need to override.

Thanks,
Pravin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through the [Implementing a Session-State Store Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) 's *Deleting Expired Session-Store Data* section.

> When the [Abandon method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon.aspx) is called for a session, the data for
>   that session is deleted from the data store using the *RemoveItem*
>   method. Otherwise, the data remains in the session data store to serve
>   future requests for the session
>
> The mechanism for deleting expired session data depends on the
>   capabilities of your data source. If your data source can be
>   configured to delete expired session data according to the session
>   Timeout property, you can use the [SetItemExpireCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatestoreproviderbase.setitemexpirecallback%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method to
>   reference the delegate for the **Session_OnEnd** event and raise it
>   when deleting expired session data.

Ref: [Delete session from database after it expired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723504/delete-session-from-database-after-it-expired)

Comment: How to find the Session Expire before it calls the Page_load event or in Global.asax using SQl Server Session Provider.

Comment: ref this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhiln/archive/2007/06/21/detecting-session-timeout-in-asp-net-2-0-web-applications.aspx) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391784/asp-net-session-expiry-redirect-to-login-page)

Comment: I tried that.That is for SessionMode="InProc". I am using SessionMode="SQLServer". How to find Session Expire when we use SessionMode="SQLServer"?

Answer (score 0):

U can manually do this by following code

> ```
> HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove("session");
> HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
> ```

Comment: I was not knowing If i call HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon(); then session Id is removed from SQL server by using built in function. I thought i manually need to override the event to delete expired session data. thanks